# outofrange exception in getpixel method

Tags: c#

i'm trying to store pixel values of an image into 2-d array using getpixel method  when the for loop reach [0,240]
i get outofrange exception any one can help me ?

```html
  // Loop through the images pixels to store in array. 
                for (x = 0; x < image1.Height; x++)
                {
                    for (y = 0; y < image1.Width; y++)
                    {
                       Color p = ((Bitmap)image1).GetPixel(x, y);
                         pic[x,y] = p.ToString();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: What is the size of `pic`?

Answer (score 1):

You are looping `x` as the height and `y` as width, but then you use them the other way to access the pixels.

Loop `x` as width and `y` as height:

```
// Loop through the images pixels to store in array. 
            for (y = 0; y < image1.Height; y++)
            {
                for (x = 0; x < image1.Width; x++)
                {
                   Color p = ((Bitmap)image1).GetPixel(x, y);
                     pic[x,y] = p.ToString();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Although I suspect he wants to do `pic[y,x] = p.ToString();` Because his array is likely addressed by `row, col` and the pixels are addressed by `col, row`. I guess it depends on whether he defined his array as `[width, height]` or `[height, width]`.

Comment: @JimMischel: Yes that's possible, but the most likely reason for the out of range expection is that the array is declared as `[width, height]`. If the array was large enouth the original code would give an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` when the `GetPixel` tried to read outside the image.

Comment: OK Mr Guffa I used your loop and it works just fine thank you for your help .

Comment: @nadahussien: If his response solved your problem, you should mark the answer as accepted (click the check mark to the left of the answer).